# Dates once selected in jquery datepicker cannot be selected again

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Am using jquery datepicker. I am able to select a date on the calender. However when I delete the date from the input box, click the calender & select the same date I previously selected, am unable to do select it. The reselected date does not show up in the input box.

Any pointers will be useful.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: Code please, let us see your code.

Comment: Vivek, you can't ask a coding question without posting your "not working" code.

Comment: Sorry folks..My error.